# How to overload two-colon operator in Scala?

Tags: scala, list, operator-overloading, builder-pattern

I was wishing to implement [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) in `Scala` by overloading list operator and `Nil`. But apparently it didn't work.

```
class SomeBuilder {

  val sb : java.lang.StringBuffer = new java.lang.StringBuffer

  def ::(str : java.lang.String): SomeBuilder = {
    sb.append(str)
    this
  }

  def Nil(): java.lang.String = {
    sb.toString
  }

}

object Hello extends App {
  println( new SomeBuilder :: "aaa" :: "bbb" :: Nil )
}
```

Why and how to succeed?

Comment: Why do you want it to be exactly `::`? There is a special semantics for operators that end in `:` in Scala that seem to not match your example. Also your `Nil` will not work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may find in the [Scala spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#infix-operations)

> The associativity of an operator is determined by the operator's last character. Operators ending in a colon ‘:’ are right-associative. All other operators are left-associative.

and a bit later:

> If there are consecutive infix operations `e0;op1;e1;op2…opn;en` with operators `op1,…,opn` of the same precedence, then all these operators must have the same associativity. If all operators are left-associative, the sequence is interpreted as `(…(e0;op1;e1);op2…);opn`. Otherwise, if all operators are right-associative, the sequence is interpreted as `e0;op1;(e1;op2;(…opn;en)…)`.

It means that your syntax

```
new SomeBuilder :: "aaa" :: "bbb" :: Nil
```

is actually interpreted as

```
Nil.::("bbb").::("aaa").::(new SomeBuilder)
```

This is done that way because `::` is an operator traditionally used in functional programming to build immutable `List` and this is exactly the semantics required there. So if you really want to use `::` you should make a code like this:

```
object Nil {

 class RealBuilder(val sb: java.lang.StringBuilder) {
    def ::(str: java.lang.String): RealBuilder = {
      sb.append(str.reverse)
      this
    }

    def ::(terminal: SomeBuilder): String = {
      sb.reverse.toString
    }

    override def toString = sb.toString
  }


    override def toString = sb.toString
  }

  def ::(str: java.lang.String): RealBuilder = {
    new RealBuilder(new java.lang.StringBuilder(str))
  }

  override def toString = ""
}

sealed trait SomeBuilder
object SomeBuilder extends SomeBuilder
```

and then

```
println(SomeBuilder :: "aaa" :: "bbb" :: Nil)
```

will work. But note how dreadfully inefficient this is: effectively you rotate every string twice. You have to do this because `::` is right-associative and there is no efficient `perpend` method.

**Sum up** you can make this syntax work but this is a really bad idea to use `::` for that. You will be better if you use literally almost anything else.

***Sidenote #1***: Using `Nil` is also a rather bad idea because it will clash with the `scala.collection.immutable.Nil` (i.e. an empty `List`).

***Sidenote #2***: Although modern JVM implementation can optimize `synchronized` out it many cases you better use [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of [`java.lang.StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) in such non-multithread environment

---

**Update the same but with `++`**

So the main problem was using `::`. If you use other operator like `++`, it should work find.

If syntax like that

```
println(new SomeBuilder ++ "aaa1" ++ "bbb2" build)
```

or

```
println((new SomeBuilder ++ "aaa1" ++ "bbb2").build)
```

is OK with you, you may use code like this:

```
class SomeBuilder {
  val sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder

  def ++(s: String): SomeBuilder = {
    sb.append(s)
    this
  }

  def build: String = sb.toString()

  override def toString = sb.toString
}
```

if you for some reason prefer something closer to your example such as

```
println(new SomeBuilder ++ "aaa1" ++ "bbb2" ++ BuildString)
```

you may use code like this:

```
class SomeBuilder {
  val sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder

  def ++(s: String): SomeBuilder = {
    sb.append(s)
    this
  }

  def ++(terminator: BuildString): String = sb.toString()

  override def toString = sb.toString
}

sealed trait BuildString

object BuildString extends BuildString
```

Comment: Okay, how to overload operators/function, to get nice builder syntax then?

Comment: In other words: is it possible to overload list creation syntax so that it creates my of class, not list?

Comment: Dima, I'm not sure what is not clear to you. You can overload operators but for any typical case you want the overloaded operator not to and with `:`. You should use operators that end in `:` only if it makes sense to build your target object "backwards" as it does for immutable `List`s